# ClamAV file size restrictions

Tags: antivirus, clamav

What is the file size limit for scanning large files with ClamAV? Is it possible to scan files as large as 20gb.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

No by default the max size is 20Mb. Use

```
--max-filesize=
```

to override it but this stops at 4Gb.

ClamAV is mainly oriented at mail servers and scanning attachments.

It has a max filesize limit in order to prevent an attacker sending a ton of big
attachments and grind the mail server to a halt as clamav slowly scans the files.

If you want to scan Linux files do not bother with ClamAV. It uses Windows rules to find Windows viruses and that will never ever work. If you need to scan a Linux server for malware you need to use a tool to search for "rootkits". Like "rkhunter".

Answer (score 0):

Don't use max-filesize without understanding what it does :

> --max-filesize=#n - files larger than this will be skipped and assumed clean

It doesn't increase the scan limit to 4G and block larger files (which may have malware).

If people know you're setting that parameter, they can wrap their malware with a 10G file from /dev/random...

Use `--max-scansize` instead.